# Store scraped table as dictionary and output as pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've scraped some data from the site given below. I'm having trouble taking the output of this data on excel. Also, I have stored the table I have scraped as dictionary. But the key and value pair are not in sync. Would somebody please help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd



url = requests.get("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/307847.html" )
soup = bs(url.text, 'lxml')
soup_1 = soup.find(class_ = "recordsTable")
soup_pages = soup_1.find_all('a', href= True)

state_links =[]

for link in soup_pages:
state_links.append(link['href'])


for i in state_links:
parse_link = "http://stats.espncricinfo.com"+i
url_new = requests.get(parse_link)
soup_new = bs(url_new.text, 'lxml')
soup_table = soup_new.find(class_="engineTable")
results = {}
newdict = dict()

for col in soup_table.findAll('th'):
    colname = (col.text).lstrip().rstrip()

for row in soup_table.findAll("td"):
    rowname = row.text.lstrip().rstrip()

newdict[col.text] = row.text
print (newdict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 loops but didn't store colname and rowname to add to newdict. Here is my solution. Please be aware of case size of val_list > size of key_list

```
# create 2 lists to store key and value
key_list = []
val_list = []
newdict = dict()
for col in soup_table.findAll('th'):
    key_list.append((col.text).lstrip().rstrip())

for row in soup_table.findAll("td"):
    val_list.append(row.text.lstrip().rstrip())

index = 0
# loop key_list and add key pair to dict
for key in key_list:                    
    newdict[key] = val_list(index)
    index += 1
print(newdict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating the list and storing in the same variable which will override every time you iterate. Try the below code I think it will work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

url =requests.get("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/307847.html" )
soup = bs(url.text, 'lxml')
soup_1 = soup.find(class_ = "recordsTable")
soup_pages = soup_1.find_all('a', href= True)

state_links =[]
state_id =[]
for link in soup_pages:
    state_links.append(link['href'])
    state_id.append(link.getText())

Total_dict = dict()

for a,year in zip(state_links,state_id):
    parse_link = "http://stats.espncricinfo.com"+a
    url_new = requests.get(parse_link)
    soup_new = bs(url_new.text, 'lxml')
    soup_table = soup_new.find(class_="engineTable")
    newdictlist = list()
    col_name =list()
    row_name =list()
    for col in soup_table.findAll('th'):
        col_name.append((col.text).lstrip().rstrip())
    for row in soup_table.findAll("td"):
        row_name.append(row.text.lstrip().rstrip())
    no_of_matches = len(row_name)/len(col_name)
    row_count=0
    for h in range(int(no_of_matches)):
        newdict = dict()
        for i in col_name:
            newdict[i] = row_name[row_count]
            row_count=row_count+1
        newdictlist.append(newdict)
    print(newdictlist)
    Total_dict[year] = newdictlist
print(Total_dict)
```

ouput:{'1877': [{'Team 1': 'Australia', 'Team 2': 'England', 'Winner': 'Australia', 'Margin': '45 runs', 'Ground': 'Melbourne', 'Match Date': 'Mar 15-19, 1877', 'Scorecard': 'Test # 1'}, {'Team 1': 'Australia', 'Team 2': 'England', 'Winner': 'England', 'Margin': '4 wickets', 'Ground': 'Melbourne', 'Match Date': 'Mar 31-Apr 4, 1877', 'Scorecard': 'Test # 2'}]
,['1879':[{'Team 1': 'Australia', 'Team 2': 'England', 'Winner': 'Australia', 'Margin': '10 wickets', 'Ground': 'Melbourne', 'Match Date': 'Jan 2-4, 1879', 'Scorecard': 'Test # 3'}],............}